# Angular / Zone.js : intercept non-angular XMLHttpRequest-s properly?

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, captcha, zone.js

I am developing an app that needs to include the Tencent Captcha. Contrary to Google's, it is not well documented and drove me to some confusion that made me reverse-engineer its obfuscated code.

For a seamless implementation, I need to get a callback when it finishes it XHR calls. These callbacks are not provided by the captcha. So, I'll have to get them myself.

To do so, I've tried to wrap the XMLHttpRequest object before Angular's boot, but it throws some errors like: `TypeError: Cannot set property '__zone_symbol__xhrSync' of undefined`.

Reading a few tutorials, book chapters and articles, I understood that this wrapping is already done by Zone.js. However, I am still not very sure whether Zone.js also wraps non-angular HXR calls or not.

If yes, how to extend it to get a callback when these are finished.
If not, how to make a proper implementation of an XHR interceptor for non-angular XHR calls in an Angular App ?

Here is an example of HXRInterceptor I've written, that won't work without error:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    XHRInterceptor: any;
  }
}

type DataSent = 
  string | Document | Blob | ArrayBufferView | 
  ArrayBuffer | FormData | URLSearchParams | ReadableStream<Uint8Array>;

export class XHRInterceptor {
  constructor() {
    ((original: Function): void => {
      XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = (data: DataSent): void => {
        console.log('DATA SENT');
        original.call(this, data);
      };
    })(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);

    (function(original: Function) {
      // @ts-ignore
      XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = (
        method: string, url: string, async: boolean,
        username?: string | null, password?: string | null
      ): void => {
        console.log('DATA OPEN');
        original.call(this, method, url, async, username, password);
      };
    })(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
  }
}
```

To call it, just put `new XHRInterceptor();` in your main.ts.

Thank you.

Comment: could you provide a reproduce repo?

Comment: I am able to intercept the XHR request, however the original `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` is not executed. Consequently, there is no http request in the browser. 

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I am able to intercept the XHR request with the code above, however the original XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open is not executed. Consequently, there is no http request in the browser.

Then I follow the code below and put it into the constructor. And it works.

https://gist.github.com/sergeimuller/a609a9df7d30e2625a177123797471e2

Comment: The link isn't working anymore. How did you do it?